# JavaScript: Check if 2 letters are subsequent letters in the alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I compare 2 letters in JavaScript to check if they are subsequent letters in the alphabet. Basically, the 2 letters have to be next to each other in the alphabet.

for example, comparing:

- `a` to `b` would be `true`
- `a` to `c` would be `false`

For my program I receive an input array such as `["a","b","e"]` and I want to loop through this array and compare each item to the one before it, below is my code:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  console.log(str);
  for(let i=1; i<str.length; i++){
    console.log(str[i]>str[i-1]);
    if(str[i] > str[i-1]){
      console.log("good order");
    } else {
      console.log("missing");
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

so far I'm not sure what to do in the inner `if statement` I just tried comparing the items to check if item at index `i` is bigger than item at index `i-1`.

Comment: Your efforts so far ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract both characters' `charCode`s, then check that they differ by 1, and are within the alphabetical range:

```js
const checkAlphaAdjacent = (c1, c2) => {
  const [code1, code2] = [c1.charCodeAt(), c2.charCodeAt()];
  return Math.abs(code1 - code2) === 1 && [c1, c2].every(char => /[a-z]/i.test(char));
};
console.log(checkAlphaAdjacent('a', 'b'));
console.log(checkAlphaAdjacent('a', 'c'));
console.log(checkAlphaAdjacent('A', 'C'));
console.log(checkAlphaAdjacent('B', 'C'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const checkSequence = (c1, c2) => {
    const char1 = c1.toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
    const char2 = c2.toLowerCase().charCodeAt();
    return Math.abs(char1 - char2) === 1;
  };
  
  console.log(checkSequence('a','B'));
  console.log(checkSequence('a','b'));
  console.log(checkSequence('B','a'));
  console.log(checkSequence('B','B'));
```

in this solution if a comes after b answer is true. if you don't want this just change this line:
return Math.abs(char1 - char2) === 1;
to
char2 - char1 === 1;
so ['a','b'] is true and ['b','a'] is false.
in other approach if you want to ['b','b'] is ok so change ===1 to <=1 and so on.